# Split frames obtained from video into separate channels

Tags: c++, opencv, video, split

I am trying to read a video (mp4) frame by frame and then convert the frames from BGR to HSV.
I then want to split the HSV Mats into different channels (Hue, Saturation, Value).

this, however, does not work:

```
void colorize () {

VideoCapture cap("myFile.mp4");
Mat frame;
Mat frame2;



while (true) {
    cap>>frame;
    cvtColor(frame, frame2, CV_BGR2HSV);
    Vector<Mat> channels;
    split(frame2, channels);




   }
}
```

The split-function gives  the following error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘split(cv::Mat&, cv::Vector<cv::Mat>&)’
     split(frame2, channels);
```

I have tried the exact same code outside of a loop with another image I had before transformed to hsv and it worked fine, so I assume the problem must be the looping.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `cv::Vector`, while instead you should use `std::vector` (note the lowercase *v*).

```
std::vector<Mat> channels; // std::vector, not cv::Vector
split(frame2, channels);
```

Comment: I'll accept in 7 minutes, stackoverflow won't let me any earlier. meanwhile, WHY do I have to use std::vector? cv::Vector worked fine outside the loop?

Comment: Are you sure? using `cv::Vector` shouldn't work, even outside a loop.

Comment: my bad. Now I am kinda ashamed for the question.

Comment: Clear question, easy solution. Everyone's happy now ;D